# cancel setTimeout inside an IIFE inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that will click on dom elements in order to show and hide them.

The function is working correctly and cycling through my dom elements however I am not able to stop the setTimeout once I call the function due to the IIFE I am using.

I've added a variable to the global space to break out of the loop however the setTimeout is already initiated so it never stops. I have also tried to assigne a name to the first setTimeout with a truthy/false flag in an attempt to catch and stop the next iteration of setTimeout in the loop but that has been unsuccessful as the console log continues when I attempt to stop the setTimeout.

```
function cycleSlides() {

    var slides = [1,2,3,4]
    var closeSlide = $(".close"); 

        for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            (function() {
                var x = i;

                setTimeout(function() {

                    if(x == 0) {
                        console.log("slides[x].click()")// first slide
                    } 
                    else {
                        setTimeout(function() { console.log("closeSlide.click()") }, 1000) // timeout for animation to finish when clicked
                        setTimeout(function() { console.log("slides[x].click()") }, 2000) // timeout for animation to finish when clicked
                    }

                    // CLOSE LAST SLIDE
                    if(x == slides.length - 1 ) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log("closeSlide.click()")
                        }, x * 1000)
                    }
                }, x * 3000)
            }(i))
        }
     }
```

Comment: Rather than starting n - 1 timeouts, why not refactor it to have a single timeout that recursively performs work, every time span?

Comment: Also just a question but the `console.log("slides[x].click()")` and the other logs in the else statement are really strange.  Those are only going to print text and not actually perform any operations.  You are aware of this?

Comment: I console logged those as placeholders. If the rest of the project was added it shows that slides is a jQuery selector for all a href elements with a class name. Without the console log, the slides[x].click() would click the element and display.

Comment: Thanks Taplar, I believe I know where you are going with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns a timeout ID that can passed to [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to cancel the timeout. You could store the timeout IDs returned by your calls to `setTimout()` in an array. Then, when you want to cancel them, call `clearTimeout()` with the values and clear the array. Here's what that code might look like:

```
var timeouts = [];

function cancelTimeouts() {
    for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {
        clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    }

    timeouts = []
}

function cycleSlides() {

    var slides = [1,2,3,4]
    var closeSlide = $(".close"); 

        for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            (function() {
                var x = i;

                timeouts.push(setTimeout(function() {

                    if(x == 0) {
                        console.log("slides[x].click()")// first slide
                    } 
                    else {
                        timeouts.push(setTimeout(function() { console.log("closeSlide.click()") }, 1000)) // timeout for animation to finish when clicked
                        timeouts.push(setTimeout(function() { console.log("slides[x].click()") }, 2000)) // timeout for animation to finish when clicked
                    }

                    // CLOSE LAST SLIDE
                    if(x == slides.length - 1 ) {
                        timeouts.push(setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log("closeSlide.click()")
                        }, x * 1000))
                    }
                }, x * 3000))
            }(i))
        }
     }
```

Comment: I needed to push the first timeout into the array and that solved the problem when calling cancelTimeouts().

Comment: Sorry, I missed that first `setTimeout()` call. I updated the answer.